# How to display first image from gallery in the container box that uses image_picker

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to display the first image in camera roll in the box like your normal apps(the tiny box where you click on to select an image) but not sure how to go about it.
Here's the code block I've tried. I don't know if I have to create a new bloc to add this feature or not. Thank you for your efforts.

```
class _CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  late CameraBloc cameraBloc;
  final GlobalKey screenshotKey = GlobalKey();
  Uint8List? screenshotBytes;
  bool isThisPageVisibe = true;
  File? image;

  void selectImage() async {
    final pickedImage = await pickImage();
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        image = pickedImage;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    // App state changed before we got the chance to initialize.
    if (cameraBloc.getController() == null) return;

    // Handle app lifecycle state changes (e.g., background, foreground)
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      // Disable the camera when the app is inactive
      cameraBloc.add(CameraDisable());
    }
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      if (isThisPageVisibe) {
        // Enable the camera when the app is resumed and this page is visible
        cameraBloc.add(CameraEnable());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      children: [
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 54, 53, 53),
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          body: VisibilityDetector(
            key: const Key("my_camera"),
            onVisibilityChanged: _handleVisibilityChanged,
            child: BlocConsumer<CameraBloc, CameraState>(
              listener: _cameraBlocListener,
              builder: _cameraBlocBuilder,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: selectImage,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 1,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
              ),
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              //color: Colors.blue, 
              child: Image.file(image),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```